# How to filter list of objects by reading one of value from other list

Tags: java, collections

We have some data which we received from UI in form of json and convereted to Java object, on which basis we have to filter the main list and store that DataObject in filterList.

```
public class DataObject implements Serializable{

private String mTaskName;
private long mCaseNumber;
......

}

//Fetching data list from session
List<DataObject> listData =(List<DataObject>)session.getAttribute("DATA_LIST");

//Variable to hold filtered data
List<DataObject> filteredData = new ArrayList<DataObject>();



public class FilterCriteria
{
private String filterName;
private String[] value;
.....
}
```

for example if we have filterName as TaskName and Value ["value1","value2"] and second filter CaseNumber also enabled with value ["2323232","4554544"]. We have to apply this logic on main List that is listData and store those records filtered one in filteredData. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about Appache Commons Collections CollectionUtils.filter? 
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate%29

Comment: but how to take care the values[] which have all values which we need to filter and store in another list. Do I need to run that in loop? Looking for best practice

Comment: I doubt there is other solution than iterate over array elements.

Comment: Okies thanks, means I have to loop through my filter values array and use this predicate thing....

Comment: Yes, this is approach. But be aware that other elements will be removed from original list, so if you need to keep them, you have to clone the list first. From other perspective, this method is just candy, you can implement it yourself with additional for each loop and copy matched element to new list. This would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can implement it in this way also if you want to go rowwise or columnwise.

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args)
     {
      List<ArrayList<String>> two_dimension=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

      //Suppose you want to make nxm dimensional list. Then you can set the values as
      int rows=4;
      int columns=5;
      for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
      {
          two_dimension.add(new ArrayList<String>());
          for(int j=0;j<columns;j++)
          {
              two_dimension.get(i).add("element"+i+j);
          }
      }


      //to accesss your element
      boolean row=true; // lets decide to traverse by row 
      if(row==true)
      {
       for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
      {
          for(int j=0;j<columns;j++)
          {
              System.out.println(two_dimension.get(i).get(j));
          }
      }
      }

      else
      {
         for(int i=0;i<columns;i++)
      {
          for(int j=0;j<rows;j++)
          {
              System.out.println(two_dimension.get(j).get(i));
          }
      }  
      }

     }
}
```